# Generalize a pair of method without lossing static typing checks

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am working with a pet project trying to practice (pure?) OO and can not figure out how to factorize a common behavior from a couple of classes.
[image]
[image]

```
public Solution improve(Solution initialSolution)
{
    stopCondition.setInitialSolution(initialSolution);

    Solution nextSolution = initialSolution;
    do
    {
        nextSolution = nextSolutionGenerator.generate(nextSolution);
    }
    while(!stopCondition.isStopConditionReached());

    return nextSolution;
}
```

As you can see, generate is common to both BinaryNextSolutionGenerator and PermutationNextSolutionGenerator. I know that Solution generate(Solution solution) should be in NextSolutionGenerator, however I do not want to lose the type verification at compile time if I send a PermutationSolution instance into a BinaryNextSolutionGenerator instance.
Looks like I have to use generic programming or my design is fundamentally wrong (or is a common tradeoff?), but I would prefer some experienced opinion before.

BTW, generate only calls doGenerate because I am planning to add some common logging code in there.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: You should create an Interface with a `generate()` method that is implemented by both solution generators. Alternatively, you can think of these as iterables and implement the Iterator interface instead for better composition with other classes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make/refactor Solution and Generator to interfaces.

   - a "good place" for generics would be to refactor `Integer getVariable(int idx)` to `<V extends java.lang.Number> getVariable(int idx)`
   - another "good generic place" is the (exact) type of `Soultion` "generator.generate"...
2. Introduce *abstract* implementations of that interfaces! And put there as much common code as you can (`public Solution<V> generate() {...}`), enforce needed methods (`<S extends Solution<V>> proteced abstract S doGenerate(S prev);`) `AbstractGenerator` is also the place, where you would put the `imporve` (and `public generate`) methods.
3. Extend these abstract classes and implement the enforced methods (with concrete implementations of the solutions)
4. same with solution builder: work with abstraction, extension

...

https://github.com/xerx593/soq54317950 explains my points better... also outlined `improve()` and `StopCondition<V extends Number, S extends Solution>`.